# Biblatex: sorting cyrillic and latin names in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, cyrillic

I'm struggling with compiling a bibliography (biblatex, biber) which includes author names in different scripts. Ideally, the bibliography would treat non-latin letters like their latin equivalents and sort them accordingly (e.g. *Достоевский* as *Dostojevski*). Instead, it seems like authors with names in the cyrillic script get placed at the end of the bibliography by default.

I figured I could use `sorting=debug` which would sort the bibliography according to the entry key. As I use *Dostojevski* instead of *Достоевский* in the entry key, this partly fixes my problem. But this way, another problem occurs: names with umlauts are not sorted correctly. In the entry key, I e.g. use *a* instead of *ä*, so this means *Täht* would be sorted as *Taht* (see MWE below). As umlauts are the last letters of the Estonian alphabet, this makes for quite a difference.

So the default order for the authors in the MWE is: *Tolkien, Täht, Достоевский*

With `sorting=debug`, I get: *Достоевский, Täht, Tolkien*

But what I actually want is: *Достоевский, Tolkien, Täht*

Is there a neat way to fix this?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Dostojevski2014,
  title={Двойник},
  author={Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский},
  year={2014},
  location = {Москва},
  publisher={Aegitas},
  langid={russian},
  shortauthor = {Dostojevski},
}

@book{Taht2020,
title = {Taevas},
author = {Põhja Täht},
year = {2020},
langid = {estonian}
}

@book{Tolkien1937,
title = {The Hobbit},
author = {J. R. R. Tolkien},
year = {1937},
langid={english}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[russian, english, estonian]{babel}

\usepackage[bibencoding=auto, backend=biber, autolang = other, style=authoryear, sorting=debug, dashed=false, citestyle=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage{xpatch, filecontents}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
        {}
        {\textbf{\printnames{shortauthor}%
         \addspace{=}\space}}}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}

\begin{document}

Citing different authors (\cite{Dostojevski2014}, \cite{Tolkien1937}, \cite{Taht2020})

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question, but `(\cite{Dostojevski2014}, \cite{Tolkien1937}, \cite{Taht2020})` can be replaced by `\parencite{Dostojevski2014,Tolkien1937,Taht2020}` (OK, that will give you semicolons between citations and not commas, but that can be changed with `\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}`)

Comment: This can be done - have a look at the transliteration support for Russian in the biblatex manual as this is explicitly meant for such a situation.

Comment: @Davislor moewe's answer below provided several solutions to my problem, so I won't have to use `sorting=debug` any longer. Changing the entry key to `taeht` wouldn't have made a difference, though: _Täht_ would have still preceded _Tolkien_.

Comment: @Kuu Okay, wrong collation order for Estonian.

Comment: *it seems like authors with names in the cyrillic script get placed at the end of the bibliography by default* -- I'm not sure what your background is, but as a user of the Cyrillic script (and a native Russian speaker), it's exactly the behaviour I'd expect. Cyrillic after Latin is the standard UX choice in my experience, so may I ask why you're trying to go against that?

Comment: @Norrius It's not a matter of personal preference, but a requirement for the paper I'm writing. I guess the reason is that a lot of Estonian scholars have published papers in Russian earlier, but nowadays publish in Estonian or English. Differentiating between scripts might therefore lead to one author appearing in different parts of the bibliography. Another reason is the use of the latinised name in the citation, due to which the latinised name also precedes the original Cyrillic name in the bibliography (e.g. Dostojevski = .Достоевский, Фёдор Михайлович 2014.).

Comment: @Kuu That's really interesting, and it's the first time I've heard of such a convention. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the MWE you are using `sorting=debug,` which sorts entries purely on their entry key. This sorting scheme is not intended for normal use, but it explains why you get the result you are getting. If you remove `sorting=debug,` (and thus get `sorting=nyt,` from `style=authoryear,`) the results for Latin script will be better with *Täht* after *Tolkien* (since it will follow Estonian conventions: unless directed otherwise `biblatex` always takes the collation rules from the main document language)

[image: Tolkien > Täht > Dostojevski]

The Cyrillic *Достоевский*, however, is now sorted after all the Latin letters.

---

`biblatex` has the option to sort fields by transliterated contents (search for `\DeclareSortTranslit` [in the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). Currently this is available for Russian and Sanskrit IAST.

So adding

```
\DeclareSortTranslit{
  \translit[russian]{setnames}{russian}{bgn/pcgn-standard}
}
```

or

```
\DeclareSortTranslit{
  \translit[russian]{setnames}{russian}{ala-lc}
}
```

to your preamble depending on the romanisation scheme you prefer, should sort *Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский* under *Dostoyevskiy, Fëdor Mikhaylovich* (`bgn/pcgn-standard`) or *Dostoevskiĭ, Fëdor Mikhaĭlovich* (`ala-lc`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, english, estonian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, autolang = other, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
    {}
    {\textbf{\printnames{shortauthor}%
     \addspace{=}\space}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareSortTranslit{
  \translit[russian]{setnames}{russian}{bgn/pcgn-standard}
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Dostojevski2014,
  title       = {Двойник},
  author      = {Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский},
  year        = {2014},
  location    = {Москва},
  publisher   = {Aegitas},
  langid      = {russian},
  shortauthor = {Dostojevski},
}
@book{Taht2020,
  title  = {Taevas},
  author = {Põhja Täht},
  year   = {2020},
  langid = {estonian}
}
@book{Tolkien1937,
  title  = {The Hobbit},
  author = {J. R. R. Tolkien},
  year   = {1937},
  langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citing different authors \autocite{Dostojevski2014,Tolkien1937,Taht2020}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

If none of these romanisation schemes float your boat, you can still force a sorting manually with the `sortname` field (transliteration copied from [Estonian Wikipedia](https://et.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fjodor_Dostojevski)).

```
@book{Dostojevski2014,
  title       = {Двойник},
  author      = {Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский},
  year        = {2014},
  location    = {Москва},
  publisher   = {Aegitas},
  langid      = {russian},
  shortauthor = {Dostojevski},
  sortname    = {Fjodor Mihhailovitš Dostojevski},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, english, estonian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, autolang = other, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
    {}
    {\textbf{\printnames{shortauthor}%
     \addspace{=}\space}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Dostojevski2014,
  title       = {Двойник},
  author      = {Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский},
  year        = {2014},
  location    = {Москва},
  publisher   = {Aegitas},
  langid      = {russian},
  shortauthor = {Dostojevski},
  sortname    = {Fjodor Mihhailovitš Dostojevski},
}
@book{Taht2020,
  title  = {Taevas},
  author = {Põhja Täht},
  year   = {2020},
  langid = {estonian}
}
@book{Tolkien1937,
  title  = {The Hobbit},
  author = {J. R. R. Tolkien},
  year   = {1937},
  langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citing different authors \autocite{Dostojevski2014,Tolkien1937,Taht2020}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

You already give a romanisation in the `shortauthor` field. If that is enough for you and you don't need the full name for sorting, you can tell `biblatex` to start considering `shortauthor` for sorting (which it normally doesn't) by adding the field to the sorting template. Note that this of course has an effect on 'normal' uses for `shortauthor` like

```
author      = {{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}},
shortauthor = {NASA},
```

which will now be sorted under *NASA* and not *National Aeronautics and Space Administration*.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, english, estonian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, autolang = other, dashed=false]{biblatex}


\DeclareSortingTemplate{nyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{shortauthor}
    \field{author}
    \field{shorteditor}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
    {}
    {\textbf{\printnames{shortauthor}%
     \addspace{=}\space}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Dostojevski2014,
  title       = {Двойник},
  author      = {Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский},
  year        = {2014},
  location    = {Москва},
  publisher   = {Aegitas},
  langid      = {russian},
  shortauthor = {Dostojevski},
}
@book{Taht2020,
  title  = {Taevas},
  author = {Põhja Täht},
  year   = {2020},
  langid = {estonian}
}
@book{Tolkien1937,
  title  = {The Hobbit},
  author = {J. R. R. Tolkien},
  year   = {1937},
  langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citing different authors \autocite{Dostojevski2014,Tolkien1937,Taht2020}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result for all three approaches is

[image: Dostojevski > Tolkien > Täht]

Comment: Thank you a lot, this was so much help! I thought there should be an easy way to fix this, but spent quite some time looking for it.

Comment: @Kuu Sorting letters from the same script is already non-trivial (contrary to what should happen in Estonian in German `ä` would traditionally sort as `ae` in names, but often simply as `a` in other words) and it gets much more complicated if you want to sort letters from a different script. While probably most languages with a Latin-based alphabet would agree that the (Russian) Cyrillic *Д* is *D*, things are far more tricky for say *В* (Germans would use "W", English speakers "V"). Saying the Latin-equivalent of *Достоевский* is *Dostojevski* commits you to a certain romanisation system. ...

Comment: ... Sometimes that system is not the result of a simple one-to-one mapping of Cyrillic characters to Latin characters, but the result of traditions and exceptions. I have seen numerous variants of *Чебышёв* (from Chebychev to Tschebyschow) for example. Sometimes Russian people are known under the French romanisation of their name in German. I doubt a humble computer program like Biber can get all of this right automatically.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that there is lots of differences, each language having their own traditions in regard to sorting letters and transliteration. I chose to go with the `sortname` option and except for having to add the transliterations manually, it really is the "easy" fix for my problem that I was looking for (easy as in convenient, easy to implement).